# How to split,reverse and concatenate video using single command in FFMPEG?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-editor, android

i want to create reverse video with audio and remov from large clip.for that first split video in segment then reverse splits video then concatenate all reverse video as single video file but it take too much time to execute all command.

i want to single command to do split,reverse and concatenate video.

first split video:

String[] cmd = {"-ss", spos, "-t", epos, "-i", videoPath, "-preset", "ultrafast", "-c:v", "libx264", "-crf", "22", "-map", "0", "-segment_time", "6", "-g", "9", "-sc_threshold", "0", "-force_key_frames", "expr:gte(t,n_forced*6)", "-f", "segment","file%3d.mp4"};

then, reverse splited video:

String[] cmd = {"-i", splitlistFiles[i].getAbsolutePath(), "-preset", "ultrafast", "-vf", "reverse", "-af", "areverse", file2.getAbsolutePath()}

finally,concatenate all reverse video as single video:

String[] cmd={"-i", reverselistFiles[i].getAbsolutePath(),"-filter_complex","[0:v0][0:a0","concat=n=N::v=1:a=1 [v] [a]","-preset", "ultrafast", "-map", "[v]", "-map", "[a]", file.getAbsolutePath()}

Please help me how can i reverse video with audio and remove audio in less time . Thanks in advance :) and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to concat the videos in the same order they were in, but with the individual videos reversed, I think you've already found the best way and there would not be a one liner.

If you concat the videos, and then reverse it, it would look like this:

`ffmpeg -f concat -safe 0 -i mylist.txt -c copy pipe: | ffmpeg -i pipe: -vf reverse reversed.mp4`

Sources:

1. https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45899585/pipe-input-in-to-ffmpeg#comment99663597_45902691
3. [How to use FFmpeg Command for Reverse Video?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/17738/how-to-use-ffmpeg-command-for-reverse-video/17739#17739)